# How to compare plain password with scrypt hashed password in Firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a question related data migration from Firebase Authentication,

if we will have to move data out of firebase authentication and in this case we get hashed password (done by scrypt), is there any way we can compare plain password with that hashed password (exported from firebase)

There is a way to get user data using auth:export (firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth), But Even if we get this data ,How do we compare plain password with hashed password stored (done by firebase using modified scrypt algo), is there a way?

I tried following below link, but no luck.

https://github.com/firebase/scrypt